# Can you subscribe to netlink events from the wpa_supplicant in linux?

Tags: events, netlink, wpa, wpa-supplicant

Given the wpa_supplicant in Linux uses nl80211, can I subscribe to one of it's multicast groups and listen for association, di-association, authentication and de-authentication events?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `ctrl_interface` in `wpa_supplicant` config file, for example:

```
ctrl_interface=/tmp/wpa_supplicant
```

Аfter you run wpa_supplicant using this config file a socket will be created. If your interface is wlan0 then path to the socket will be `/tmp/wpa_supplicant/wlan0.`

You can connect to this socket and read events using [wpa_ctrl_recv](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/wpa__ctrl_8h.html#a9665f27035cf2af8b9b7530b6b49b4e6). Events are actually plain text but you can parse them.

You only need to include necessary functions to your project somehow. As for me, I've simply copied part of wpa_supplicant sources (wpa_ctrl.h, wpa_ctrl.c and some other included files) to my project. But probably there's some library which you can use.